# OPL Transportation

Tags: cplex, opl

I am writing a code for a simple transportation problem in IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio.
Here is the code
trans.mod (File)

```
{string} Sources = ...;
{string} Destination = ...;
float Demand[Destination]= ...;
float Output[Sources]= ...;
float Shipcost[Sources][Destination]= ...;

assert sum(s in Sources) Output[s] == sum(d in Destination) Demand[d];
dvar int Ship[Sources][Destination] in 1..50;
minimize 
sum(s in Sources, d in Destination)
Shipcost[s][d]*Ship[s][d];
subject to 
{
forall( s in Sources , d in Destination )
sum(d in Destination)
Ship[s][d]<=Output[s];
forall( s in Sources , d in Destination )
sum(s in Sources)
Ship[s][d]>=Demand[d];
forall( s in Sources , d in Destination )
Ship[s][d]>=0;
}     
execute DISPLAY
{
writeln("Ship=",Ship)
}
```

The data file of it is as
trans.data

```
Sources = {Source1 Source2 Source3};
Destination = {mumbai delhi vadodra kolkata};
Demand = #[
        mumbai: 80
        delhi: 65
        vadodra: 70
        kolkata: 85
        ]#;
Output = #[
        Source1: 75
        Source2: 125
        Source3: 100
        ]#;
Shipcost = #[
        Source1: #[
                    mumbai: 464
                    delhi: 513
                    vadodra: 654
                    kolkata: 867
                    ]#
        Source2 : #[
                    mumbai: 352
                    delhi: 416
                    vadodra: 690
                    kolkata: 791
                    ]#
        Source3 : #[
                    mumbai: 995
                    delhi: 682
                    vadodra: 388
                    kolkata: 685
                    ]#
            ]#;
```

The problem is that when I run this simple transportation problem on TORA it gives me Optimal Solution as 152535
But when I run this code on cplex it gives me optimal solution as 156366
Please let me know where I am going wrong or why i am getting the difference of 3831.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question is that did both Tora and cplex give the optimal results? There is no gap for both of them right?

If both are optimal results, check parameters if you input into one of the programs wrongly.

Check and compare decision variables for both program whether the result is the most logical result for the optimal solution or not.

Comment: I have already cross-checked the values. For your reference, i have attached the value table in the given link.[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzbsKTQxAozfd2hTS1VzRmQxbE0/view?usp=sharing] @FatihCen . Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: // solution (optimal) with objective 156366
Ship = [[29
             14 19 13]
             [50 50 1 24]
             [1 1 50 48]];
This is the result i am getting in CPLEX. And from tora https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzbsKTQxAozfSGVfeUt0SzBJcWM

Comment: I think I found your mistake. When I checked results, tora gives the right solution and if you check the cplex result it gives maximum 50 value from a supply point to demand point. You put an upper bound for your decision variable for 50. If you increase it, problem will be solved. dvar int Ship[Sources][Destination] in 1..50;

Comment: Thank You @FatihCen it worked I changed the range of variable from 0...100.

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as the solution if it worked?