# Senstivity analysis in cplex

Tags: cplex, opl

I am trying to figure out How can I do the sensitivity analysis in CPLEX IDE.
I am new to CPLEX I have made a transportation problem 
please refer to the link below
[OPL Transportation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585931/opl-transportation)
I just want to know what would be the SYNTAX for sensitivity analysis or how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may get some info in the IDE.

With:

```
dvar float+ Gas[1..2][1..2];
dvar float+ Chloride[1..2][1..2];

dvar float obj;
maximize
 obj; 
subject to {
ctObj:obj==sum(i,j in 1..2 )(40 * Gas[i,j])  + sum(i,j in 1..2 ) (50 * Chloride[i,j]);

   forall(i,j in 1..2) ctMaxTotal:     
    Gas[i,j] + Chloride[i,j] <= 50;
   forall(i,j in 1..2 )ctMaxTotal2:    
     3 * Gas[i,j] + 4 * Chloride[i,j] <= 180;
   forall(i,j in 1..2 ) ctMaxChloride:  
      Chloride[i,j] <= 40;
}
```

you'll get:

[image]

if you click on a decision variable.

In CPLEX documentation, you also have some info at:

- IDE and OPL > Optimization Programming Language (OPL) > Language User’s Manual > The application areas > Applications of linear and integer programming > Linear programming
- Sensitivity analysis